# Return Selection from LonglistSelector to calling Page in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a mainpage with a Button with some content. I want to open a second page or popup in witch i must have a longlistselector with X items in it. when i choose one of them i want to change the content of the button to the selected item.

I can make the main page and the second page i dont know how to send back the result to the first page. ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "MVVM Light" library then you can use Messenger service Like this....

in second page after selection is changed send a message

```
Messenger.Default.Send<type>(message,token);
```

and then in the consructor of page 1 viewmodel

```
Messenger.Default.Register<type>(this,token,Method);
```

here token should be same as sender token....

then

```
void Method(type message)
{
  button.content = message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Popup to show your LongListSelector ,and when set   `popupElement.IsOpen=false;` the set Button Content same as required,

If you wish to change content as selected list then use `popupElement.IsOpen=false;` on selection change method and get selected item there.

Remember use selection change method on page not inside popup child class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a separate page to show the longlistselector, then you could try something like this.

```
//in long list page, 
Void longlist_SelectionChanged()
{
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["key"] = longlist.selecteditem;
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}

//in your main page where the selected data has to be displayed..
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("key"))
    {
        Button.Content = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["key"];
    }
}
```